# Unable to run secure remove (srm) command from AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, macos

I am unable to run the command [`srm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srm_(Unix)) in macOS 10.12, Sierra. I can run the command in Terminal.app but not from within an AppleScript.

This command works:

```
srm -rf /Users/Jack/.Trash/
```

This command fails with `error "sh: srm: command not found" number 127`:

```
do shell script "srm -rf ~/.Trash/*"
```

`srm` is not present in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: What is the result of `which srm` ?

Comment: How does the command fail, is there any error message? Does it work if you add the full path to `srm` in AppleScript?